# Android:Attendance idea

Tags: android

I am doing an attendance take up proj. I have all my sudent names in listview.now i want  an
idea how can i mark a student present or absent?

If I use check boxes either I am able to retrive all rows or I am able to retrive only checked boxes rows.I wanted to do that if the check box for that row is clicked,it should go to if loop and retrieve row data over there and  I will manually write there present and it gets stored in database  or it should go to else loop and manually I will write absent.but I dont think its possible  to use if else  like I mentioned.

Can any one please guide me how can I mark a student present or absent?

Comment: I can't understand what is being asked here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea with the checkbox is ok. You can set a clicklistener (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)) for each checkbox. The checkbox can be accessed in the adapter class of your listview (I assume that you use a custom list adapter for your listview). For example if you are using an ArrayAdapter you can handle the click event in the getView method when you override it (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getView(int, android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup)). Here you have the position of the clicked checkbox item and you can access the row data based on the position. If you want to write manually "present" or "absent" you can use a message dialog which has an EditText.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use CheckedListView and can set list mode to list.setChoiceMode(ListView.Multiple); you can get all the set items by getSelectedItems(), it would return a sparced array, actual values selected might get by parsing this sparce array.

Comment: thks fr reply i wll try this.

Comment: @SnehaKoneru please, could you try to write correct words? "thks", "fr" and "wil" aren't real words...